# python unable to open file over https in imagemagick policy error

Tags: python, http, https, imagemagick

i am opening the remote file(pdf) using image magic python lib but i am getting error

If i use link with **http** its working fine but with **https** i am getting error like

```
wand.exceptions.**PolicyError**: not authorized `HTTPS' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1717
```

and i edited my policy of https none to read

below is image magic lib the policy is in Ubuntu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policymap [
<!ELEMENT policymap (policy)+>
<!ELEMENT policy (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST policy domain (delegate|coder|filter|path|resource) #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy name CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy rights CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy pattern CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy value CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
<!--
  Configure ImageMagick policies.

  Domains include system, delegate, coder, filter, path, or resource.

  Rights include none, read, write, and execute.  Use | to combine them,
  for example: "read | write" to permit read from, or write to, a path.

  Use a glob expression as a pattern.

  Suppose we do not want users to process MPEG video images:

    <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="mpeg:decode" />

  Here we do not want users reading images from HTTP:

    <policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="HTTP" />

  Lets prevent users from executing any image filters:

    <policy domain="filter" rights="none" pattern="*" />

  The /repository file system is restricted to read only.  We use a glob
  expression to match all paths that start with /repository:

    <policy domain="path" rights="read" pattern="/repository/*" />

  Let's prevent possible exploits by removing the right to use indirect reads.

    <policy domain="path" rights="read" pattern="@*" />

  Any large image is cached to disk rather than memory:

    <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="1GB"/>

  Define arguments for the memory, map, area, width, height, and disk resources
  with SI prefixes (.e.g 100MB).  In addition, resource policies are maximums
  for each instance of ImageMagick (e.g. policy memory limit 1GB, -limit 2GB
  exceeds policy maximum so memory limit is 1GB).
-->
<policymap>
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="temporary-path" value="/tmp"/> -->
  <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="256MiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="map" value="512MiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="16KP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="16KP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="128MB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="1GiB"/>
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="file" value="768"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="thread" value="4"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="throttle" value="0"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="time" value="3600"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="precision" value="6"/> -->
  <!-- not needed due to the need to use explicitly by mvg: -->
  <!-- <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="MVG" /> -->
  <!-- use curl -->
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="read" pattern="URL" />
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="read" pattern="HTTPS" />
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="read" pattern="HTTP" />
  <!-- in order to avoid to get image with password text -->
  <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*"/>
  <policy domain="cache" name="shared-secret" value="passphrase" stealth="true"/>
  <!-- disable ghostscript format types -->
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="EPI" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="PDF" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="XPS" />
</policymap>
```

is this lib only support http files instead of https?

Comment: You have `<policy domain="delegate" rights="read" pattern="HTTPS" />`, which should be allowing you to read via https. Be sure you are looking at the correct version of the policy.xml file. See https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php for possible locations. Also be sure that Wand has access to the correct policy.xml file. I am not an expert on Wand to know how or if it uses the policy.xml file.